# Simple C++/CLI SerialPort ReadByte (at least, so I thought...)

Tags: c++, arduino, byte, rs485

So, I am working with C++/CLI in VisualStudio and an Arduino based board. My goal is to implement MODBUS via RS485.

So the setup I have for development is as follows...

Laptop connected Via FTDI USB-RS485 interface cable to Maxim MAX3485 chip which is connected to Arduino serial port "Serial1".

I have been writing my MODBUS protocol in Visual Studio and testing it out by asking the Arduino to respond with the contents of 5 registers (a 5 byte array).
Everything works except for some reason, return bytes are getting split in two when I check the result.

I.E... I'm sending the following bytes from the Arduino:

```
0 A 0 14 0 1E 0 28 0 32
```

A is actually "0A", but the terminal window only displays it as "A". The software on the computer receives the bytes, and stores them in an array. I then display the bytes received on the screen as text. What I get is:

```
0 A 0 1 4 0 1 E 0 2 8 0 3 2
```

Which looks correct, except the space between the "1 & 4", "2 & 8" etc.. which is telling me that I have 14 bytes instead of the 10 bytes the I sent out.

I'm displaying each byte on the screen separated by a space. I verified the bytes leaving are correctly formatted using a terminal window on a separate com port, so the problem must be in the reading of the bytes?

My Arduino code:

```
// Print to terminal window to verify bytes leaving
  Serial.print("Sending:-  "); 
  for (int x = 0; x < i_Index; x++) {

    Serial.print(DataTxRegister[x], HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");

  }
  Serial.println(" ");


  // CONFIGURE 485 CHIP TO TX MODE
  digitalWrite(CNTL_PIN, HIGH);
  delay(5);

  // TRANSMIT ALL DATA FROM TX REGISTER
  for (int x = 0; x < i_Index; x++) {

    Serial1.print(DataTxRegister[x], HEX);

  }

  i_Index = 0;
  delay(5);
  // CONFIGURE 485 CHIP BACK TO RX MODE
  digitalWrite(CNTL_PIN, LOW);
```

Visual Studio code

Read Bytes....

```
int8_t Byte;
// DATA RECIEVED FROM ARDUINO / DEVICE USING MODBUS PROTOCOL
if(sender == this->serialPort1){

    Msg.Message_Length = 0;
    while (this->serialPort1->BytesToRead != 0) {

    Byte = this->serialPort1->ReadByte;         
    if (Byte != -1) {

        Msg.Incoming_Bytes[Msg.Message_Length++] = (Byte);
    }


    }

this->BeginInvoke(gcnew EventHandler(this, &Form1::DisplayMBRecieved));
}
```

Display Bytes...

```
this->textBox1->AppendText("\r\n");
this->textBox1->AppendText("Bytes Received: ");
this->textBox1->AppendText(Convert::ToInt32(Msg.Message_Length).ToString("X8") + "  :-  ");

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Msg.Message_Length; i++) {

    this->textBox1->AppendText(Convert::ToString(Convert::ToChar(Msg.Incoming_Bytes[i])));

    this->textBox1->AppendText(" ");

}

Msg.Message_Length = 0;
```

Comment: Several critical bugs in this code.  First one certainly is that your DataReceived event doesn't actually receive a message.  You normally only get one or two bytes, serial ports are slow and modern computers are fast.  Which makes setting Message_Length back to 0 a bug.  And an especially nasty one, your BeginInvoke() call does not pass the data you received.  Now you have a threading race bug, the DataReceived event keeps in firing and modifying Msg while your UI thread displays Msg.

Comment: Ok, so how do I pass the data? Is it instead of the keyword `this` in the  `BeginInvoke ` method?

Comment: No.  Use Invoke() instead of BeginInvoke() so this bug cannot bite.  Add some Debug::Print() statements so you can see what you actually receive.  Test at a low baudrate.

Comment: Whats are the differences between the two methods?

Comment: I have verified that this is a Visual Studio issue (or my code most likely). I viewed the return data using Putty and the data bytes were correctly formatted when sent from the Arduino, and when received at the computer.  When using my VS software, for some reason, reading these bytes is splitting the high and low nibbles up into separate bytes....?